# List elements share same $index Angular js value?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to give the class "active" to each filter clicked/ I tried using `$index` but since there a multiple list items with the same `$index` (because I am repeating `ul` too) multiple list elements get the class active. Is there another way to do this?

**HTML:**

```
<div class="filter-options">
  <ul class="filters" ng-repeat="type in filterTypes" type="type.category">
    <li ng-repeat="filter in type.filters" ng-click="selectFilter($index)" ng-class="{'active': selectedFilter == $index}">{{filter.value | uppercase}}class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

**Directive:**

```
return {
    restrict: "E",
    templateUrl: 'scripts/directives/all-filters.html',
    link: function(scope, el, attr) {           
        scope.filterTypes = dummyData.filters;

        scope.selectFilter = function(filterChosen){                
            scope.selectedFilter = filterChosen;
        };
    }
}
```

Comment: Use `$parent.$index` if you are referring index of `parent ng-repeat`

Comment: @RayonDabre Can you refactor this code using $parent.$index. I don't see how this will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send the object in the parameters and add a Boolean in the function like

**Markup**

```
<li ng-repeat="filter in type.filters" ng-click="selectFilter(filter)" ng-class="{'active': filter.active}">{{filter.value | uppercase}}class="glyphicon glyphicon-menu-down"></span></li>
```

**Directive**

```
scope.selectFilter = function(clickedFilter){                
            clickedFilter.active = true;
        };
```

Hope it helps